# db2 special character 0x1A

Tags: sql, db2

How can I seach for a special character like "→" (0x1A)?
An example for my query is:

```
select * from Data where Name like '%→%'
```

I want to use instead of "→" something like 0x1A.

I can't use any Java or C# Code. I just have SQuirrel to connect and send commands to the database.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17462802/1699210)

Answer (score 2):

You can use chr() to search the charater:

```
select * from data where name like '%' + chr(26) + '%'
```

Comment: That would be `chr()`, `char()` is a cast.

Answer (score 1):

Old topic, but a current issue nevertheless. My DB2 environment runs on AS400/iSeries and use EBCDIC instead of ASCII. I worked out the character from the EBCDIC table at [lookuptables.com](http://www.lookuptables.com/ebcdic_scancodes.php).

ASCII 0x1a translates to SUB, and SUB translates to EBCDIC 0x3f.

Using that in SQL looks like this:

```
select productDescription
from productsTable
where productDescription like '%' || x'3F' || '%'`
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Use `chr(26)`.

Solution 2: Write the query in Java or another programming language which lets you build the SQL from pieces and where you can enter hex codes.

Answer (score 0):

This query has worked for me in the past on iSeries DB2.

```
select * from db/table where posstr(field, x'3F') > 0
```

Trouble is you have to be certain of the hex value you are searching for in the string.  I had a similar situation where the I was sure the hex code for the character was x'3F, but when I sub-string the non-viewable character it was actually x'22. You might want to single out the character that is giving you the issue and see what it's value is.

```
select hex(substr(field, 21,1)) from db/table where posstr(field, 'StringBeforeCharacter') > 0
```