# Extract digits from character field in SQL

Tags: sql, db2, alias, squirrel-sql

I am moving data from a column in one database to a column in another database using the INSERT INTO command using Squirrel SQL v3.7.

The field I am moving is a character field for telephone numbers that allowed open entries.
The receiving field however should disregard all letters and symbols and only enter in the format ##########

Is there a simple way to do this?  The other solutions I've seen have been very involved.

Comment: Are you extracting from DB2 and inserting into DB2? Could you handle the replace at the source database?

Comment: The first thing that jumps to my mind is regular expressions.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763757/regular-expressions-in-db2-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462802/how-to-find-special-characters-in-db2/17469776#17469776

Answer (score 0):

Try this when extracting, or only the translate when inserting the data:

```
select translate('+ 4854 BBBB cCc 12','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()-=+/\{}[];:.,<>? ',' ') from yourTable;
```

Comment: I think you mixed up the "from" and "to" strings.

Comment: And seems likely to be incomplete for the domain of *all letters and symbols* except for those, perhaps aptly described as, USA-centric. A specification of hex code points devoid of only the digits would be quite complete; perhaps to excess, and would be dependent on encoding scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not specifically familiar with Squirrel sql, but the easiest way to match non-numeric is with regex.  Specifically [^0-9] will match anything in the string that is not a number.  I was able to obtain the result described above on my system (ibm iseries) with a:

```
select regexp_replace(column1,'([^0-9])','') from table1
```